# Stop Chrome from cascading windows when I restart Win 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Why does chrome insist on cascading its windows when I restart Win 10? ***I want my windows to restore to the size and place I left them***, like it used to. I cannot find a setting for that or any info googling it. Thanks.

Comment: Try closing Chrome before restarting. It may come back the way you left it. Simple Chrome setup does come back for me that way.

Comment: I usually do close Chrome before restarting. No help.